# Including .bash_profile over ssh

Tags: ssh, bashrc

I am trying to write a script that will:

1. Copy files to a server (I already have a script `copy.sh` that does this task)
2. ssh to that server
3. cd to the directory where the files I just copied are
4. run `make`
5. copy the resulting binary from `make` to another location.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
BUILDSERV=me@server
BUILDDIR=/me/directory

#run my script that copies the files
./copy.sh

#TARGET is also a var in copy.sh so I make sure it's set properly here
TARGET=root@final_dest:/usr/bin/my_bin

ssh $BUILDSERV "cd $BUILDDIR && make && scp ./my_bin $TARGET"
```

The issue is that a program I want to run as part of `make` is not in my `PATH`. My `.bash_profile` has a `export PATH=$PATH:/my/bin/` line, but it seems that `bash_profile` is not being read when I ssh in.

Is there a way to change my ssh invocation or script in general to make it read my `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Have you considered using a forced command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ssh $BUILDSERV "source ~/.bash_profile && cd $BUILDDIR && make && scp ./my_bin $TARGET"
```

The `source` shell builtin reads a file and executed the commands in the same shell (unlike simply calling the script, which invokes a separate shell).

When invoked as login shell, `bash` executes the `.bash_profile`, if it exists, in exactly the same way as `source` does, therefore the effect will be the same.

Comment: I found this explanantion from superuser.SE about `source` http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do